# os.chdir() doesn't work when executing the code in console

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, python-os

I am building a recommendation system using the `surprise` package and `Python 3.6`. I have a class named MovieLens that loads the dataset and also does some data preprocessing. The `os.chdir()` function works correctly upon script execution but raises an error when executed in ipython console.
Here's my MovieLens class:

```
import csv
import sys
import re

from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import Reader

from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

#__file__ = 'MovieLens.py'
class MovieLens:

    movieID_to_name = {}
    name_to_movieID = {}
    ratingsPath = '../ml-latest-small/ratings-mine.csv'
    moviesPath = '../ml-latest-small/movies-mine.csv'

    def loadMovieLensLatestSmall(self):



        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
        print(os.getcwd())

        ratingsDataset = 0
        self.movieID_to_name = {}
        self.name_to_movieID = {}

        reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating timestamp', sep=',', skip_lines=1)

        ratingsDataset = Dataset.load_from_file(self.ratingsPath, reader=reader)

        with open(self.moviesPath, newline='', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as csvfile:
                movieReader = csv.reader(csvfile)
                next(movieReader)  #Skip header line
                for row in movieReader:
                    movieID = int(row[0])
                    movieName = row[1]
                    self.movieID_to_name[movieID] = movieName
                    self.name_to_movieID[movieName] = movieID

        return ratingsDataset
```

My working directory is: `F:\RecSys-Materials\Framework`
and the datasets are located in the directory: `F:\RecSys-Materials\ml-latest-small`

And my anaconda is installed in the directory: `C:\Users\Samarth\Anaconda3`

I looked at the `sys.argv` argument and it returns an empty list. i also tried using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` but spyder doesn't recognize the `__file__` variable.

I understand that that `os.path.dirname()` must be passed a path. So why does this work when i execute the script? What am i missing here?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You said `but spyder doesn't recognize the __file__ variable`. I think that should be working if you're using our latest version (3.3.4). So please update and try again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I am using spyder 3.3.4. These are some other tools i am using ```Python 3.6.8 32-bit | Qt 5.9.6 | PyQt5 5.9.2 | Windows 10 ```. Will reading trouble shooting guide help?